# Regex based on address in any order

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex based on an address format :
`([0-9-]*) ?([\p{L}*,\. '-]*) ?([0-9 ]*) ?([\p{L}*,\. '-]*) ([0-9]{5}) ?([\p{L}*,\. '-]*)`

It can match with this :
16 Rue du Pont Louis-Philippe 75000 Paris

But I'd like to get this regex match with this format too :
75000 Paris 16 Rue du Pont Louis-Philippe

Can someone help me pls ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of optional parts in the pattern. You can make the last 2 groups optional, but you would have to change the quantifiers to 1 or more times using `+` to prevent partial matches (Or add `^` to the pattern to assert the start of the string)

```
([0-9-]+) ([\p{L}*,. '-]+) ([0-9 ]+) ([\p{L}*,. '-]+)(?: ([0-9]{5}) ([\p{L}*,. '-]+))?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JQH0GW/1)

Comment: Thank you it works !
But I have another problem, I have different pattern of address :
`16 Rue du Pont Louis-Philippe 75000 Paris`

`75000 Paris 16 Rue du Pont Louis-Philippe`

`16 Rue du pont Louis-Philippe 1er 75000 Paris`

`75000 Paris 16 Rue du pont Louis-Philippe 1er`

Comment: @Octaz Are these all variations? Matching an address can be quite challenging due to all the different notations.